# Mongoose - Agrupar por campo de array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, apollo

Estoy trabajando en una query que recibe un array de ids (personIds) como parámetro y quisiera agrupar la respuesta por id recibido pero no logro hacerlo. Estoy trabado en este punto.

Tengo este Schema:

```
extend type Query {
   racePersons(personIds: [String!]): [PersonRaceByIds]
}

type PersonRaceByIds{
     _id: ID!
     competitors: [Competitor]
}

type Competitor {
    pos: String,
    person_id: String,
    person_name: String,
    age: Int,
}
```

Obtengo esta respuesta:

```
"racePersons": [
      {
        "_id": "60cf1129e1e449ceee12c87c",
        "competitors": [
         {
        "person_id": "60cf111de1e449ceee12b89d",
        "pos": "1"
      },
      {
        "person_id": "60cf111de1e449ceee12b958",
        "pos": "8"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "60d4e8063a4409433c673ad2",
    "competitors": [
      {
        "person_id": "60cf111de1e449ceee12b89d",
        "pos": "3"
      }
    ]
```

Pero quiero agrupar por los parámetros que recibo. Por ejemplo si ejecuto:

```
RaceByPersons(personIds: ["61cf111de1e449ceee12b958", "61cf111de1e449ceee12b89d"]) {
_id
competitors {
   person_id
   pos
 }
}
```

Quisiera obtener algo como esto, si es posible:

```
61cf111de1e449ceee12b958 [{
      {
        "_id": "60cf1129e1e449ceee12c87c",
        "competitors": [
         {
        "person_id": "60cf111de1e449ceee12b89d",
        "pos": "1"
      },
      {
        "person_id": "60cf111de1e449ceee12b958",
        "pos": "8"
      }
    ]},
  61cf111de1e449ceee12b89d [{
  {
    "_id": "60d4e8063a4409433c673ad2",
    "competitors": [
      {
        "person_id": "60cf111de1e449ceee12b89d",
        "pos": "3"
      }
    ]
  ]}
```

Intenté usando "group" con aggregate() pero no lo consigo.
personIds son los parámetros.
Por ejemplo: ["61cf111de1e449ceee12b958","61cf111de1e449ceee12b89d"]

Este es mi resolver:

```
.aggregate([
{
    $match: { 'competitors.person_id': { '$in': personIds } }
},
{
    $project: {
        competitors: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$competitors",
                as: "r",
                cond: {
                    '$or': [
                        { '$in': ['$$r.person_id', personIds] }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        _id: 1,
    },
},
```